Is there a way to simulate the arrival of a package on an interface using scapy
For testing and debugging purposes, I'd like to be able to simulate the arrival of a package on a specific interface and have it then regularly go through the entire network stack. Is this possible using scapy? Are there other ways to do it ?


Is this possible using scapy?

Likely not, here the Scapy documentation discusses specifics of loopback interface and its usage: link.

Are there other ways to do it ?

I can only recommend connecting two machines and sending packets from one machine two another. One can use virtual machines, for example, created in VirtualBox, to do experimenting with only one physical machine available.


I can only recommend connecting two machines and sending packets from one machine two another.

We already do that and that's exactly the use-case I was trying go simplify
